# Replace values in character vector using lookup table in R

Tags: r

I have something like this:

```
  #Change deg
  x1 <- gsub("&deg;","°",x1)

  #Change ohm
  x1 <- gsub("&ohm;","Ω",x1)

  #change divide
  x1 <- gsub("&divide;","÷",x1)

  #change minus
  x1 <- gsub("&minus;","-",x1)
```

But there are many values and I do not want to write everything in the r script. I have a table where it looks like this

```
&newtonm;   N m 
&reg;   ®
&deg;   °
&minus; -
```

How do i lookup the table and make the changes in the R script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how this could be done using [`Reduce()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html):

```
lookup <- data.frame(pat=c('&newtonm;','&reg;','&deg;','&minus;'),rep=c('N m','®','°','-'),stringsAsFactors=F);
lookup;
##         pat rep
## 1 &newtonm; N m
## 2     &reg;   ®
## 3     &deg;   °
## 4   &minus;   -
entityrep <- function(x) Reduce(function(x,r) gsub(lookup$pat[r],lookup$rep[r],x,fixed=T),seq_len(nrow(lookup)),x);
x1 <- 'test &newtonm; &reg; &deg; &minus; test';
entityrep(x1);
## [1] "test N m ® ° - test"
```